# I am having problems with longtable

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a longtable with the title at the top. I am new to writing documents with latex, and I think that I almost have it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{longtable}{rllllllll}
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 0.0093683 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.0584e-06 \\

3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 0.025626 \\

4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 0.15359 \\

5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 0.15359 \\

6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 0.15359 \\

7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 0.025626 \\

8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.7334e-13 \\

9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 0.025626 \\

10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 0.063937 \\

11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 0.063937 \\

12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 0.0061408 \\

13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 0.025626 \\

14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 0.025626 \\

15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 0.049111 \\

16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 0.049111 \\

17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 0.0061408 \\

18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 0.0002252 \\

19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.6646e-06 \\

20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.6646e-06 \\

21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.6688e-18 \\

22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.6688e-18 \\

23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 0.010591 \\

24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.2319e-21 \\

25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.2319e-21 \\

26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 0.022611 \\

27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 0.071718 \\

28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 0.0054575 \\

29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 0.025626 \\

33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 0.001173 \\

34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 0.001173 \\

35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 0.049111 \\

36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 0.049111 \\

37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.0584e-06 \\

38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 0.071718 \\

39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 0.025626 \\

40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 0.020895 \\

41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 0.08329 \\

42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 0.071718 \\

43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 0.0093683 \\

44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 0.0093683 \\

45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 0.15359 \\

46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 0.0093683 \\

47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 0.025626 \\

48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 0.025626 \\

49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 0.0061408 \\

50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 0.022611 \\

51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.0584e-06 \\

52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.0584e-06 \\

53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.4899e-11 \\

54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 0.015 \\

55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 0.0093683 \\

56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 0.0093683 \\

57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 0.022611 \\

58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 0.0015206 \\

59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 0.034353 \\

60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.1411e-21 \\

61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.1411e-21 \\

62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 0.025626 \\

63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 0.04362 \\

64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 0.025626 \\

65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 0.11977 \\

71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 0.0038256 \\

72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 0.0038256 \\

73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 0.022611 \\

74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.5131e-06 \\

75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.5131e-06 \\

76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.5131e-06 \\

77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.5131e-06 \\

78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 0.0061408 \\

79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 0.025626 \\

80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 0.0080506 \\

81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\caption{Amplified Genes in Breast Cancer}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The problems are that I get "Table 2" in the title (I only have one table), and the longtable doesn't split correctly. I am pretty sure that I am not seeing a blatant mistake. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions/observations:

- Don't encase a `longtable` inside a `table` environment. (A `table` environment cannot contain page breaks.)
- If you want to place the `longtable`'s caption at the start of the material, simply place the `\caption` instruction immediately after `\begin{longtable}{...}`.
- Be sure to organize the table's headers and footers via the instructions `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot`.

The first few rows of the table thus might look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot

  1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 0.0093683 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.0584e-06 \\

3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 0.025626 \\

4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 0.15359 \\

5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 0.15359 \\

6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 0.15359 \\

7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 0.025626 \\

8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.7334e-13 \\

9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 0.025626 \\

10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 0.063937 \\

11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 0.063937 \\

12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 0.0061408 \\

13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 0.025626 \\

14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 0.025626 \\

15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 0.049111 \\

16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 0.049111 \\

17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 0.0061408 \\

18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 0.0002252 \\

19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.6646e-06 \\

20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.6646e-06 \\

21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.6688e-18 \\

22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.6688e-18 \\

23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 0.010591 \\

24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.2319e-21 \\

25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.2319e-21 \\

26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 0.022611 \\

27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 0.071718 \\

28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 0.0054575 \\

29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 0.022611 \\

32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 0.025626 \\

33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 0.001173 \\

34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 0.001173 \\

35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 0.049111 \\

36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 0.049111 \\

37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.0584e-06 \\

38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 0.071718 \\

39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 0.025626 \\

40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 0.020895 \\

41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 0.08329 \\

42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 0.071718 \\

43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 0.0093683 \\

44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 0.0093683 \\

45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 0.15359 \\

46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 0.0093683 \\

47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 0.025626 \\

48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 0.025626 \\

49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 0.0061408 \\

50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 0.022611 \\

51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.0584e-06 \\

52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.0584e-06 \\

53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.4899e-11 \\

54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 0.015 \\

55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 0.0093683 \\

56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 0.0093683 \\

57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 0.022611 \\

58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 0.0015206 \\

59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 0.034353 \\

60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.1411e-21 \\

61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.1411e-21 \\

62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 0.025626 \\

63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 0.04362 \\

64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 0.025626 \\

65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 0.025626 \\

70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 0.11977 \\

71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 0.0038256 \\

72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 0.0038256 \\

73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 0.022611 \\

74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.5131e-06 \\

75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.5131e-06 \\

76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.5131e-06 \\

77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.5131e-06 \\

78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 0.0061408 \\

79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 0.025626 \\

80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 0.0080506 \\

81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am trying to add two tables together with "\clearpage". The amplification table comes out like you created. The deletion table is off... I am studying your code. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Johnathan - If you have two `longtable` environments, be sure to use distinct `\label` instructions (and use each label separately in the header of `\endfoot`). Also, if you have `\hline\hline` as the material for `\endlastfoot`, don't insert `\hline\hline` again at the end of the table. If you need to separate two consecutive `longtable`s visually, I wouldn't do so via a `\clearpage` instruction`; something line `\bigskip` (or `\bigskip\bigskip` should be enough.